# Spring Data JPA - how to make intermediate query in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Promotion, PromotionDetail, Product entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "promotions")
public class Promotion implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "promotion",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private Collection<PromotionDetail> promotionDetails;
}
```

====

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "product"
    )
    private Collection<PromotionDetail> promotionDetails;
}
```

====

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "promotion_details")
public class PromotionDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "promotion_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("promotionDetails")
    private Promotion promotion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "product_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"promotionDetails"})
    private Product product;
}
```

from the above entities i want to find a solution at ProductRepository to get list of Products based on Promotion Id
i tried with line of code like this but it doesn't work:

```
Page<Product> findProductsByPromotionDetails_Promotion_Id(long id, Pageable pageable);
```

can someone please help me
it's pretty simple right
Examples of data are as follows:

```
Product:
id
--------------
P0882021035821
P0882021035822
P0882021035823
P1482022025430
Promotion:
id  discount
-------
1   12
2   13
3   12

Promition_Detail
id      product_id      promiotion_id
1   P0882021035821  1
2   P0882021035823  1
3   P1482022025322  1
4   P1482022025430  5
5   P1482022025322  5
```

when i execute above query to get list product with promotion _id = 1 I have a product list that has product_id like:

```
P0882021035821
P0882021035823
P1482022025322
P1482022025322
```

the issue is i have double product have product id equals P1482022025322
and the result I want is a list like this:

```
P0882021035821
P0882021035823
P1482022025322
```

when I execute : `findProductsByPromotionDetails_Promotion_Id(1,1);`

Comment: That's impossible in an interface query because product and promotion are not directly related.

Comment: Tks, So do you have any ideas that can help me do this?

Comment: i think i can do the above if i execute a query but i dont know how to apply Pageable function in that query

Comment: @Kira you can add a query using [`Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming) passing `Pageable` as one of the methods parametrs

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an exception? If so post the stack trace. Do you get wrong results? If so, what data is in the database, what result did you expect? What result did you get?

Comment: I have provided a sample of the data and results when executing the query and the results I want. hope someone can help me find the solution. about using Pageable in @Query, can someone give me the answer